How does the arithmetic for how many bytes are saved by row-compressing a datetime add up?
Everything that follows is quoted from the datetime row here. I have broken the quote to give commentary on my understanding.

Uses the integer data representation by using two 4-byte integers. The integer value represents the number of days with base date of 1900-01-01.

In other words, we have eight bytes to work with. This is exactly the same as what datetime already takes up.

The first 2 bytes can represent up to the year 2079. Compression can always save 2 bytes here until that point.

In other words, until 2079 we are losing two bytes to the year. After that point, we will lose more. This means that for dates before 2079, we have six of our original eight bytes to work with.

Each integer value represents 3.33 milliseconds. Compression exhausts the first 2 bytes in first five minutes [sic] and needs the fourth byte after 4PM.

In other words, after 4 PM we only have two of our remaining six bytes to work with.

Therefore, compression can save only 1 byte after 4PM.

This is clearly the part I misunderstand. My earlier arithmetic proves that we have two byes left. However, Microsoft says that we only have one. This is doubly confusing, because if we are past 2079 then Microsoft's numbers would put us as having negative one bytes left.

When datetime is compressed like any other integer, compression saves 2 bytes in the date.

The user has no control over how the compression works, so this line is entirely irrelevant.
From the above, it's evident that I have a great misunderstanding. What have I missed?

Pay no attention to the documentation for datetime row compression; it's nonsense. I can only assume the author conflated several ideas about datetime storage, in memory and in persistent storage.
The fact of the matter is that datetime is compressed as a single eight-byte value, with four bytes for the date preceding four for the time portion. The date bytes are a signed integer* for days before or after the base date. The time bytes are the integer number of ticks (1/300s) after midnight.
The effect is that column descriptor storage for row compressed datetime depends almost exclusively on the date, not the time portion.
The only date on which time comes into play is the base date, '1900-01-01', because it is encoded as zero in the date part and all those zeroes can be compressed away.
The physical storage needed on that one date alone depends on the number of bytes needed to encode the time portion. For midnight on the base date, the storage size is zero as normal for row compression.
The number of row-compressed bytes needed for datetime is summarised below:



StartDate
EndDate
Bytes




1753-01-01
1810-04-14
7


1810-04-15
1899-08-25
6


1899-08-26
1899-12-31
5


1900-01-01
1900-01-01
0-4 (depends on time)


1900-01-02
1900-05-08
5


1900-05-09
1989-09-18
6


1989-09-19
9999-12-31
7



For most common datetime values (natively eight bytes), you can expect to save one or two bytes.
Example
Since the documentation mentions always saving two bytes for dates before 2079, let's see how '31 Dec 2078' is stored:
CREATE TABLE dbo.CompressDateTime 
(
    pad char(8) NOT NULL,
    dt datetime NOT NULL
)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);

INSERT dbo.CompressDateTime
    (pad, dt)
VALUES
    (REPLICATE('X', 8), CONVERT(datetime, '20781231', 112));

Using DBCC PAGE:

The date is 65,378 (0xFF62) days after the base date. That number won't fit into the signed range of two bytes (-32,768 to +32,767) so three bytes are needed.
Three bytes can accommodate 16,777,216 values and half that range is 8,388,608. Applying the bias to our number of days gives 65,378 - 8,388,608 = -8,323,230 (0x80FF62).
You can see the encoded date bytes 80FF62 in the screenshot, followed by four zero bytes for the time component, giving a total of seven bytes row compressed storage.

* Column descriptor short format only stores positive values. Negative numbers are accommodated by applying a bias of half the unsigned range. For example, -1 in one byte format is stored as 127 (0x7f), after applying a bias of 128 (half the single byte unsigned range).
